# Trouble reading Modbus registers: Exception Response(131, 3, GatewayNoResponse)

Tags: python, pymodbus

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I am currently working on a Python script to retrieve data from a Modbus-enabled device, specifically a central measuring unit installed in an electrical cabinet. I am facing an issue where I receive the following error message:
"Error reading registers: Exception Response(131, 3, GatewayNoResponse)
"
The script is intended to read holding registers from the Modbus TCP IP device and print the corresponding values. However, I am encountering difficulties, and the values are not being displayed.
Here is the Python code snippet I am using:

```
from pymodbus.constants import Endian
from pymodbus.payload import BinaryPayloadDecoder
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusTcpClient

def read_modbus_registers(host, port, unit_id, starting_address, register_count):
    # Create a Modbus TCP client
    client = ModbusTcpClient(host, port)

    try:
        # Connect to the Modbus TCP server
        client.connect()

        # Read holding registers
        result = client.read_holding_registers(starting_address, register_count, unit=unit_id)

        if result.isError():
            print("Error reading registers:", result)
        else:
            decoder = BinaryPayloadDecoder.fromRegisters(result.registers, byteorder=Endian.Big)
            uint32_values = [decoder.decode_32bit_uint() for _ in range(register_count // 2)]
            print("32-bit uint values read from Modbus registers:", uint32_values)

    except Exception as e:
        print("Error:", e)

    finally:
        # Close the Modbus TCP connection
        client.close()

# Modbus settings
modbus_host = '192.168.50.6'
modbus_port = 502
modbus_unit_id = 0x01
modbus_starting_address = 0
modbus_register_count = 161

# Call the function to read Modbus registers
read_modbus_registers(modbus_host, modbus_port, modbus_unit_id, modbus_starting_address, modbus_register_count)
```

``
`

I would appreciate any insights or guidance on why I'm encountering the "GatewayNoResponse" error and how I can successfully retrieve and display the Modbus register values.

I've attempted to read Modbus registers from a central measuring unit in an electrical cabinet using a Python script. Here are the steps I've taken and the observed results:

Script Execution:

Executed the Python script that establishes a connection to the Modbus TCP server.
Attempted to read holding registers starting from address 0 with a count of 161.
Expected Outcome:

Expected the script to successfully read the Modbus registers and print the corresponding 32-bit unsigned integer values.
Actual Outcome:

Encountered the error message: Error reading registers: Exception Response(131, 3, GatewayNoResponse).
The script did not print the expected 32-bit unsigned integer values.
Any insights into why I'm facing the "GatewayNoResponse" error and guidance on successfully retrieving and displaying Modbus register values would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hello moiscs, the error you see means you have no connection with the device. You should make sure you have a network connection properly set up. Are you able to ping your device? The error message can also be related to your device having a different slave ID than the one you are using.

Comment: Hello moiscs, just like Marcos G. said it seems that your equipement is unreachable. To troubleshoot this issue, first thing I would suggest you to do is to try reading values with a software dedicated to. Just like ModBusDoctor for example, that way you will be able to know if you are in capacity of reaching the equipement. On top of that if you are able to see the data, you will know that the problem comes from your code. And also you will be able to see if your data have a special format (Big endian, Little endian or some weird ones like siemens B2B3B1B4 for example). Hope it helps cheers.